# Are there any ways to put a tiff next to another tiff using software or python code?

Tags: python, image, arcgis, tiff

Now I'm dealing with many satellite images and the format of them are tiff
The image are separate and I want to put them next to each other.

eg. I have two images and they are 2*2 pixels, ImageA lower left is (0, 0) and upper right is (2, 2) of imageA on the Cartesian coordinate system; the lower left is (10, 10) and upper right is (12, 12) of imageB.

Then I want to put imageB next to imageA which means the imageB will be relocated to lower left: (3, 3) upper right: (5,5)
However, I only have the idea but don't know which functions or skills to realize it.
I searched the net and always get a way named mosaic, but that doesn't meet my needs.

Does anybody know how to do that with software (Arcgis or etc.) or python code

Software will be better but python code is ok too.

Comment: Do you know the final image size (fixed width, height)? what are the image names?

Comment: If you want to take two tiffs and output another tiff, see [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for Python. It can also work with many other kinds of input and produce many other kinds of output.

Comment: Can you show a diagram or provide your input and output images. I am really confused about what you want. Your discussion is not very clear to me. Imagemagick has many ways to put two images together.

Comment: The input will be Sentinel-2 tiff images, then I will do the segment, the processed image 10*10 pixels.  I will choose different places which means the processed image will be separate so I want to put them together in order not to leave blank between them. Sorry for explain poorly, I will do my best  to explain everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **ImageMagick** just in your Terminal on macOS, Linux or Windows like this:

```
magick background.tif -colorspace rgb red.tif -geometry +10+30  -composite blue.tif -geometry +50+70 -composite result.tif
```

[image]

The `-geometry +X+Y` specifies the x and y coordinates of where the image will be composited onto the background.

---

Here are the input images and how I made them:

**Background**

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:gray background.tif
```

[image]

**Red**

```
magick -size 10x10 xc:red red.tif
```

[image]

**Blue**

```
magick -size 20x20 xc:blue blue.tif
```

[image]

---

You can do the same thing with PIL/Pillow in Python using:

```
from PIL import Image
# Create background image and open two overlay images
bg   = Image.new("RGB", (100,100))
red  = Image.open('red.tif')
blue = Image.open('blue.tif')

# Paste the overlays at same positions as ImageMagick code
bg.paste(red, (10,30))
bg.paste(blue, (50,70))

# Save the result
bg.save('result.tif')
```